# Transposing the matrix in perl

Tags: perl, matrix

I am trying to perform a transpose on a data contained in a file. The data is as follows:

> 1 2   3   4   5
>
> 2 3   4   5   6
>
> 4 5   6   7   9
>
> 4 3   7   6   9

I am getting the result as follows which is incorrect. I am not getting the error in the code due to which the last column is not transposed properly. Any solution...

[image]

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @dependent;    # matrix of dependent variable

# Reading the data from text file to the matrix
open( DATA, "<example.txt" ) or die "Couldn't open file , $!"; #depenedent

# Storing data into the array in matrix form
while ( my $linedata = <DATA> ) {
    push @dependent, [ split '\t', $linedata ];
}
my $m = @dependent;
#print  "$m\n";
my $n = @{ $dependent[1] };
#print  $n;


#print "Matrix of dependent variables Y \n";
for ( my $i = 0; $i < $m; $i++ ) {
    for ( my $j = 0; $j < $n; $j++ ) {
        #print $dependent[$i][$j]," ";
    }
    #print "\n";
}

my @transpose;
for ( my $i = 0; $i < $n; $i++ ) {
    for ( my $j = 0; $j < $m; $j++ ) {
        $transpose[$i][$j] = $dependent[$j][$i];
    }
}


for ( my $i = 0; $i < $n; $i++ ) {
    for ( my $j = 0; $j < $m; $j++ ) {
        print $transpose[$i][$j], " ";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: Doing matrix algebra of any kind in Perl would not be my first choice especially as the matrices get larger.  But you can do it with this:  http://search.cpan.org/~ulpfr/Math-Matrix-0.8/Matrix.pm

Comment: Would suggest using 3 arg open with lexical filehandles as better style. e.g. `open ( my $input, '<', 'example.txt' ) or die $!` and then `while  ( my $linedata = <$input> ) {`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) your data when you read it, before you split it; your strange output is caused by the last element of each row of the input still having a newline attached.

Just as a side note, `DATA` isn't a very good name to pick for a filehandle; perl already defines a [special builtin filehandle named DATA](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Special-Literals) for reading data that's embedded in a script or a module, so using that name for yourself can lead to confusion :)

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that lexical filehandles are better style too - so `DATA` is a moot point then.